# best way to insert an image in href

Tags: javascript, dom, greasemonkey, href

I am looking for the best way to insert an image with greasmonkey into a href. The picture should be there where now the text (??????) is.

```
   // ==UserScript==
   // @name           ...
   // @description    ...
   // @include        http://website/
   // @version        1.0
   // ==/UserScript==
    var links = document.getElementsByClassName( 'xyz' );
    for ( var i = 0; i < links.length; i++ ) {
    var link = links[i];
    var newlink = document.createElement( 'a' );
    newlink.href = link.href.replace( 'value=10', 'value=20' );

    newlink.textContent = '??????';

    var nextNode = link.nextSibling;
    link.parentNode.insertBefore( newlink, nextNode );
    var delim = document.createTextNode( ' - ' );
    link.parentNode.insertBefore( delim, newlink );
    }
```

Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var links = document.getElementsByClassName( 'xyz' );
for ( var i = 0; i < links.length; i++ ) {
    var link = links[i];
    var newlink = document.createElement( 'a' );
    newlink.href = link.href.replace( 'value=10', 'value=20' );
    var the_image = document.createElement('img');
    the_image.src = '';//Place image source file path here
    newlink.appendChild(the_image);

    var nextNode = link.nextSibling;
    link.parentNode.insertBefore( newlink, nextNode );
    var delim = document.createTextNode( ' - ' );
    link.parentNode.insertBefore( delim, newlink );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Insert the following lines instead of the one with the `???`:

```
var myImg = document.createElement('img');
myImg.src= 'path/to/image';
newlink.appendChild(myImg);
```